# Query cache for MariaDB Galera cluster

Tags: mysql, cache, haproxy, mariadb, galera

I've read from multiple sources now that you can't have query caches with Galera, but my current application could really benefit from a query cache. I'm load-balancing this cluster with HAProxy and am curious if HAProxy has any kind of caching ability or if there is an easy solution to this problem I'm just missing?

Answer (score 1):

Since MariaDB Galera cluster versions 5.5.40 and 10.0.14 you can use the query cache. Earlier versions do NOT support the query cache.

See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/optimization-and-tuning/buffers-caches-and-threads/query-cache/#limitations

Answer (score 0):

You could run into inconsistent data if you introduce separate caches elsewhere than inside MySQL. And I think that is the reason in the first place why Galera has no query cache.

The application should have its own cache with memcached, where required data would be stored.